# Angular 10 Download file from firebase link without opening into new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have stored user files into Firebase Storage and on listing page I've added a button to download that file. I want to start download on button click without opening that file into same or new tab. Here is the demo [file](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/crud-1054b.appspot.com/o/Profile%2FCapture_1615893100292?alt=media&token=b3e68741-d21c-424e-acd1-f5d4c63e34c5).

I've tried these solutions but each one of the following open the file into new tab and then I manually download the file:

```
window.open(row.url, 'Download')
```

```
 <a href="{{row.url}}" download>
```

```
function download(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    link.click();
}
```

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

Also tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver package

Here is link of `stackblitz` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8tna47?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Can anyone help me fining my required solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution as per new chrome specification https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Vanilla  JavaScript

```
public static downloadFile(url: string): void {
     const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
         const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(xmlHttp.response);
         const e = document.createElement('a');
         e.href = blobUrl;
         e.download = blobUrl.substr(blobUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         document.body.appendChild(e);
         e.click();
         document.body.removeChild(e);
       }
     };
     xmlHttp.responseType = 'blob';
     xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
```

If you're using angular try this.

```
async downloadBrochure(url: string) {
    try {
      const res = await this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
      this.downloadFile(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.body.message);
    }
  }

  downloadFile(data) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const e = document.createElement('a');
    e.href = url;
    e.download = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.click();
    document.body.removeChild(e);
  }
```